# Excel VBA, naming arguments causes "invalid procedure call or argument" Error 5

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA script that creates a Table (a `ListObject`) from a range stored in the variable `Storytable` and then applied list formatting.

The positional parameter version of this line works fine:

```
Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, StoryTable, , xlYes)
```

I would prefer to use named parameters, but naming the parameters causes an "invalid procedure call or argument" error (Error code 5) on this line:

```
Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=StoryTable, TableStyleName:=xlYes)
```

even though this is pretty much identical to the example provided for the `ListObjects.Add` method in the Excel online help.

A bit of experimentation has shown that even naming just the final parameter `TableStyleName:=xlYes` in the first version of this line is enough to trigger the error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is the correct signature `Function Add([SourceType As XlListObjectSourceType = xlSrcRange], [Source], [LinkSource], [XlListObjectHasHeaders As XlYesNoGuess = xlGuess], [Destination], [TableStyleName]) As ListObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth parameter to which you originally supplied `xlYes` is called `XlListObjectHasHeaders`, not `TableStyleName`. `TableStyleName` is the sixth parameter, and it does not accept `xlYes` as a valid option.

The [online help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155(v=office.15).aspx) is not only wrong in naming the parameters, it's also outdated and does not include `TableStyleName`.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!  I need to be more wary of the online help obviously.